# mysql use alternative name in switch construction

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I try to get select with code below

```
Select `admin`.`admin_id`, `admin`.`email` AS `admin_email`, IF(customer.email IS NOT NULL OR admin_email IS NOT NULL, 'Subscribed', 'Unsubscribed') AS `field_name`, (...Something else) from admin, customer, (...Something else);
```

Then get error `#1054 - Unknown column 'admin_email' in 'field list'`

Comment: You cannot use aliases in the same `select` clause.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Please stop using comma based Implicit joins and use [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

Comment: @juergen d where i must to use alias?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use alias in the if statement, so

Select `admin`.`admin_id`, `admin`.`email` AS `admin_email`, IF(customer.email IS NOT NULL OR admin.email IS NOT NULL, 'Subscribed', 'Unsubscribed') AS `field_name`, (...Something else) from admin, customer, (...Something else);